# Django makemigrations is creating migrations for model with managed = False

Tags: python, django

While Django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#managed
mentions the use of managed = False field in meta is used to not create migrations

I am still getting migrations when I call makemigrations.

This is the meta of the model:

```
class FieldOpsBooking(models.Model):
    .
    .
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'field_ops_booking'
```

And I am getting this after makemigrations
`python manage.py makemigrations`

```
Migrations for 'user_analysis':
  user_analysis/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model FieldOpsBooking
    - Create model RewardManagementLeads
Migrations for 'od_engagement':
  od_engagement/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model NormalisedTonnage
```

And it creates 0001_initial.py file with all migrations to apply as well.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can use `abstract=True` in Meta. I think that should work.

Comment: @AjayLingayat That works , add it as an answer

Comment: Please have a look in the 0001_initial.py and check if a new table is generated - I guess not, because your code seems correct

Comment: @Razenstein Yes a new table is created in 0001_initial.py. As Ajay Lingayat commented, adding abstract = True, it is working fine. Doesn't create any migrations

Comment: You will get the same problem as soon as you define a "real" class based on your abstract class! Did you do the first makemigrations without managed=false?

Comment: @Razenstein I didn't call makemigrations on it before. This was the first time. I won't be creating another model from this one. Yes but for someone else it might create a problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I checked my own projetcs with models having managed=False: YES there is an entry in migrations file like:

```
    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='xyz',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'xyz_table',
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),
```

BUT: this will not create a new table on database level when you execute "makemigration".
Sorry if a insiste but your original solution was absolutely correct!!

this is from django documentation about abtract base class:
" ... since it is an abstract base class.  .... and cannot be instantiated or saved directly."

Comment: I get it, saw this now , and tried to migrate, doesn't impact the original db

Comment: Described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/migration-operations/#altermodeloptions "Does not affect the database, but persists these changes for RunPython instances to use."

Answer (score 4):

You can set `abstract=True` in Meta to prevent model from migration as follows:

```
class FieldOpsBooking(models.Model):
   .....
   class Meta:
       abstract = True
   .....
```

Comment: This does the job but looks like django won't populate the manager i.e. objects making it non queryable.

Comment: abstract=True and managed=False are two different things. You managed=False for an existing table in an existing DB. abstract=True means that you are not expecting this table to have corresponding table.